# shell script: running cmd that was passed into a function

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a bash script:

```
function run_cmd
{
    CMD="$@"
    echo ">>> $CMD"
    exec $CMD
}

CLUSTERS_PKG="abc1, abc2"
# run command
run_cmd "package upload -c '$CLUSTERS_PKG'"
```

However, when I run this command, I get a usage error with the 'package' command. If I run the command with a copy+paste, it works fine.

It doesn't seem to like me passing in $CLUSTERS_PKG variable with spaces and quotes around it. How do I properly run "everything" that is passed into run_cmd w/o the shell clobbering things?

Comment: Possibly of interest: [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to read [the link posted by Adrian Frühwirth](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). This answer is really just a short summary of the advice found there.

---

If you pass the argument like this:

```
run_cmd "package upload -c '$CLUSTERS_PKG'"
```

then you'll have to use `eval` in your function so that the single quotes are treated as quoting operators:

```
run_cmd () {
    CMD="$@"
    echo ">>> $CMD"
    eval "$CMD"
}
```

---

If you pass the arguments like this:

```
run_cmd package upload -c "$CLUSTERS_PKG"
```

then you can use an array in your function (much safer than using `eval`):

```
run_cmd () {
    CMD=( "$@" )
    echo ">>> ${CMD[@]}"
    "${CMD[@]}"
}
```

You don't really *need* to use `exec`; in fact, you probably don't, as that causes the current process to be replaced by `CMD`: you won't return to the shell that called `run_cmd` after `$CMD` exits.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BASH ARRAYS:

```
function run_cmd
{
    arr=( "$@" )
    echo ">>> ${arr[@]}"
    exec "${arr[@]}"
}
```

Comment: If `$CMD` is quoted, the entire string is passed to `exec` as the name of a command to execute. The array solution should work, though.